# Is everyone's sense of power always predicated on diminishing that of someone else's?

Tags: free-will, nietzsche, society, nihilism, altruism

Why think that everyone's sense of power always predicated on diminishing that of someone else's, and is it the case? I think the question isn't a trivial "no reason to think it".

> power lies not in just any form of opposition, but in the
> feeling of actively resisting, of ‘striving against’ a resistance

[The Equivocal Use of Power in Nietzsche’s Failed
Anti-Egalitarianism (PDF)](https://philarchive.org/archive/MIYTEU-2)

It seems this supposes that our sense of power ***actively*** resists that of someone else, which strongly suggests it will be more active when their power is less. I don't mean a "zero sum game", but that there is no gain without loss.

> Zero-sum game is a mathematical representation in game theory and
> economic theory of a situation that involves two sides, where the
> result is an advantage for one side and an equivalent loss for the
> other.

Though more liberal definitions of the phrase exist. If it's at all reasonable, is this reason to think morality is meaningless in the sense of us having no moral obligations.

Comment: I'm curious to see where this goes . . . this is a topic I'll touch upon in my dissertation actually (hence why I cannot post an answer: would be shameless self-promotion).

Comment: hahah @Hokon you can always leave a comment on your conclusion or are we in open conflict?

Comment: i think it's philosophy gone mad to think that people cannot co-operate @Hokon especially if that is legitimatised with culture.

Comment: I don't think we're on opposite ends of this issue (I'm probably more extreme): I'm pretty much convinced of pacifism by this point, and would argue we won't have peace until we give up the quest for power. Sadly, won't happen any time soon . . . but, I find immense meaning regardless of my dismal view of things (tragic optimism you might call it).

Comment: ahh cool @Hokon yeah, the future is tragic

Comment: i don't understand anything. do we have free will, does that mean morality is bunk, would it even matter if it were @Hokon maybe i'll give up and just try to be the change i want to see lol

Comment: Why? Power in morality is not like conserved energy in classic physics at all, otherwise ethics would be subsumed into physics long time ago. Per Bacon's famous equality motto '*knowledge is power*', one's sense of knowledge is not predicated on diminishing another's knowledge and the usual JTB knowledge is not quantum thus cannot interfere with each other. Rather, opinions without firm understanding of its underlying knowledge is easily swayed and interfered by other opinions...

Comment: You might want to improve the question. (1) In its current state, the answer to the question in the title clearly is "no", and @DoubleKnot explained some reasons for that. That answer eliminates the reason of being of the rest of the post. (2) Asking both why something *might* be the case and whether it *is* the case lacks definiteness. (3) It is unclear "*whose power [you] want to see*", whose acts you intend to respond, and why are tags "Nietzsche" and "nihilism" relevant to the question.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by 2 @IñakiViggers and 3 nietzsche is a philosopher who is primarily concerned with nihilism and power (so why not answer for him?). idt 1 is all *that* relevant.

Comment: @prof_post I think re: (1) the issue is why treat power as a zero-sum game, which you post is basically asking. Supplying the motivation for this would alleviate this concern.

Comment: i'm not sure that the answer is that obvious. [this](https://philarchive.org/archive/MIYTEU-2) paper may point in the direction of "yes" for nietzsche, though i disagree and think "no" anyway

Comment: i haven't read the article, and am just showing that the question isn't trivially incoherent @Hokon

Comment: i'm not sure i mean a zero sum game @Hokon which is too strong, only that every gain entails a loss (not that they are equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the enlightened pursuit of ones own happiness coincides with the
> happiness of the community as a whole...[not a] zero sum game

Thanks for the phrase.

Friedrich Nietzsche: A Philosophical Biography - Page 310

This is (allegedly, though I agree instinctively) unlike Machiavelli's, Hobbes', Clausewitz's and Foucault's theories of power. FWIW I agree power isn't like that, though I don't understand why Nietzsche acts the way he does - like a universal benefit is worthless - if so.

Maybe what is key is that, while there may be no point hating yourself for other people, your actions do affect them in many ways.

Comment: Why does Nietzsche see the world in terms of realpolitik?

Comment: Zero sum thinking is common in society today, and it's nothing more than game theoretic terminology for "being out for yourself". As to why did Nietzsche gravitate towards [realpolitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik)? That's a psychological question, however, if you really look at how human beings interact, unfettered and optimistic altruism are both rare (because they are exploited by bad actors) and so looking at the world, one could get the impression, particularly if one is libertarian in one's thinking, that the world is fundamentally dog-eat-dog. Hobbes certainly thought so.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to Nietzsche, so if you approach the question about the [philosophy of Friedrich Nietzsche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_Friedrich_Nietzsche) within the context of [will to power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power), AND if one is working with a [psychological interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power#Interpretations) of his theory, then the response is clear. No, because that would be [zero sum thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power#Interpretations). From WP:

> Zero-sum thinking perceives situations as zero-sum games, where one person's gain would be another's loss. The term is derived from game theory. However, unlike the game theory concept, zero-sum thinking refers to a psychological construct—a person's subjective interpretation of a situation. Zero-sum thinking is captured by the saying "your gain is my loss" (or conversely, "your loss is my gain").

In a metaphysical interpretation, things become less clear. You go on to ask:

> It seems this supposes that our sense of power actively reacts and resists that of someone else, which strongly suggests it will be more active when their power is less. If it's at all reasonable, this reason to think morality is meaningless?

Indeed. Modern psychology have a parallel to the notion our sense of power actively resists, and that is related to the concepts of [reactivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactivity_(psychology)) and [reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactance_(psychology)). From WP:

> In psychology, reactance is an unpleasant motivational reaction to offers, persons, rules, or regulations that threaten or eliminate specific behavioral freedoms. Reactance occurs when an individual feels that an agent is attempting to limit one's choice of response and/or range of alternatives.

Therefore, from a highly naturalized epistemological approach, one can argue that [psychological altruism even from a Darwinian perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism#Evolutionary_explanations) suggests that morality is necessary and advantageous, and that the conflict inherent between an individual's needs and society's needs are in tension necessarily. This of course, moves the conflict of will to power to groups of people, and brings us neatly to another bias related to zero sum bias, the bias of [in- and out-group thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-group_and_out-group). Now, we see why morality is not meaningless, because it derives its meaning from **the social-psychological purpose of morality, an organizing force among individuals**.

Thus, morality, which we are biologically wired to have, is a [sociobiological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociobiology) phenomenon, and is not meaningless, but meaningful and impactful. This sheds light on the struggle of organized religion, and ties in Nietzsche's objection to religion as an opiate of the masses neatly. Freedom, free will, and will to power is endemic to political philosophy, and it should be no surprise that followed to its ends, liberalism leads to [critical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_theory) in its modern practice.

Comment: you don't show your point, which is disappointing, especially as you consider it so obvious. anyway, zero sum game is the wrong term for what i asked.

Comment: you must understand how annoying it is to ask a question which you think the answer is "no" and have the polemical response that it is so obviously no that it's barely worth answering, while failing to answer the question. i would suggest working on reading questions better than writing long answers

Comment: why do you think it's a zero sum game? i can see that sense if every relation of power is viewed impersonally such that each *side* has the goal of having as many *winners* as possible. idgi, sorry

Comment: sorry, i don't demand you understand, but saying surely you do. evidently you do not. maybe no fault. why are you calling my question egotistical like it's obvious why it is rather than a random insult?

Comment: suppose i was asking if it was a zero sum game. in no way is your rhetoric passable as a reason to believe it isn't.

Comment: what? don't bother answering questions you don't care about. it doesn't come off as apathetic, but ignorant and arrogant

Comment: right ok you care about the question but not what i meant by it. that does make sense,

Comment: my apologies, i didn't read the wp quote closely enough. a better quote than wp would be gratefully received :)

Comment: i wasn't rude to you, and i think that's the only reason to start insulting someone as you have done. maybe ymmv, in which case it's probably a cultural thing. idk

Comment: i didn't mean to insult you anyway. i felt that you provided the wrong sort of references.

Comment: I like the answer, but I still think that morality can be 'meaningless' even though it is "the organizing force among individuals". Gravity is meaningless and non-moral although it is the force between everything.

Comment: No insult taken, and no insult intended. :D I could do better than WP, but you get what you pay for. ; )

Comment: @ScottRowe It depends on which sense of meaningless you use. And I would be careful of equivocation on the metaphorical force of causality in explanation and the literal force of causality in the physical universe.

Answer (score 0):

Dimishing the power of another only yields power for the diminisher in the fashion of looking thinner by hanging out with fatter people.

Power belongs to the individual, and it is amassed independent of the condition of others.